# How to capture data in a DropDownListFor in a form and pass it to the routeValues

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this is fairly simple, and asked often, but wiring it all together is still new to me.

Each `Invoice` has an Id:

### Model

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I use the `viewModel` to populate a list of selections for a dropdown, which works great. After returning to a new view, `Main`, the `viewModel` is also used to capture the InvoiceId of the selection from the dropdown.

### viewModel

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var viewModel = new MainPageViewModel
    {
        Invoices = _context.Invoices.Where(i => i.User.Id == userId).ToList();
    };

    return View("Main", viewModel);
}
```

And I want to use razor: `@Html.BeginForm()` to route to the `{controller}/{action}/{id}` URL using this cshtml:

### View

```
@model SubSheets.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(
           action: "WorkSummary", 
           controller: "Invoices", 
           routeValues: new { id = Model.InvoiceId }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                expression: m => m.InvoiceId, 
                new SelectList(
                    Model.Invoices, 
                    dataValueField: "Id", 
                    dataTextField: "Name"
                )
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Go To Invoice" class="btn btn- 
default" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

And then simply use convention in the new view, which is building the URL correctly. The problem is the `id == 0` no matter which selection is selected.

```
public ActionResult WorkSummary()
{
    return View();
}
```

As I understand it, the lambda expression in the `DropDownListFor` determines the data hook in the `viewModel` object and the `dataValueField` of the `SelectList` captures the selection's `Id` in this case and assigns it to the expression.

I assumed it would complete the assignment and pass the `Id` to the `viewModel` and pass that through to the `routeValues` after submitting the form, however it passes `0` instead of the correct `Id`.

If I load the new view with the viewModel, I can render the `id` correctly using razor on the page. E.g.:

```
@using SubSheets.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel
<p>@Model.InvoiceId.ToString()</p>
```

What am I missing here?

### Edit:

I've tried  moving the dropdown outside of the form and making a separate submit button:

```
        <a href="@Url.Action("WorkSummary", "Invoices", new {id = Model.InvoiceId })"><button class="btn btn-default">Button</button></a>
```

I feel like I'm trying to force a square peg into a circular opening. Am I going about this incorrectly?

### Edit2

Well, I came up with a different solution. Realizing I want to use the `Url` helper, I used Bootstrap to make each selection clickable which is way sleeker anyway.

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            aria-expanded="false">
                Select Invoice <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var invoice in Model.Invoices)
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action(
                                 "WorkSummary",
                                 "Invoices",
                                 new {id = invoice.Id},
                                 null)">
                    @invoice.Name
                </a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```

then pass the `id` into the controller, query the database and return the correct entry with the correct URL. It's Ok to spend half a day on something that took me 5 minutes to actually build, right?